# iOS Strange white space in the bottom of iPhone 5

Tags: ios, layout, iphone-5

I know there are a lot of threads about this subject and most of the problems are solved by adding the default & default@x2 images.
In my app i have these images and still i have the white space, more then that the white space appears only once in the app.

I'll explain more: 
Once the user opens the app the view appears and the white space also appear, then if the user navigate to another view (the current view stays on the stack always) and goes back to the view the white space disappears.

If i exit the app and closes it from the app manager and launch the app again the white space returns.

this is an image from the app

[image: app image]

It's hard to tell because of the white background, but there is a white 
space there.

I don't know if it is related but i'm getting this logs once the app is running:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x796300b0 H:[UIImageView:0x79630250(18)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7962f800 H:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x79630610'BATTLEFIELD FRIENDS']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79630700 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7962e850 H:[UIImageView:0x79630250]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79630700 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7962e880 H:[UILabel:0x79630610'BATTLEFIELD FRIENDS']-(5)-[UIImageView:0x79630250]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7962ec10 H:[UIView:0x79630700]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79630a20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7962ec40 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x79630700]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79630a20 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x797beeb0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x79630a20(50)]>"
)
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have edited this code with some logs i got

Answer (score 0):

Given that the whitespace is only on the bottom of the screen shot, and is white, not black, I don't believe this is a result of the default@2x images.
It sounds like the bounds of your view aren't getting set correctly when the view is first loaded.  Is this view created via code or a nib?  Without more information on your setup, it would be tricky to solve.  But, this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: you are right, sorry for not adding this info. this view is created via nib file, and it uses autolayout also.

Comment: Can you share your auto layout constraints?

Comment: I create the constraints in StoryBoard, not by code.